# Is const in placement new superfluous?

Tags: c++, constants, placement-new

This problem ocorred to me while trying to implement a `std::any` like container.

Is the usage of `const` in `placement new` superfluous?

If not, what does it mean?

Should I use `std::decay` on `placement new`?

```
#include <iostream>

int
main() {
    auto * address = std::malloc(sizeof(std::string));

    // What does `const` means here?
    // Is it superfluous?
    // Is `std::decay` needed here too?
    new (address) std::string const("hello, world");

    // Is this undefined behaviour?
    // In the context of my code: T -> std::decay<T>
    // Here I'm just using a `std::string` as an example
    auto & str = *static_cast<std::string *>(address);

    str.append("hi");

    std::cout << str << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need it.  Just use `new (address) std::string{"hello world"};`.

Comment: In theory, allocating read only memory is valid. In practise, no one allocates memory that they can't write to.  So `const` in new is useless - if it works at all.

Comment: As Davis weites, it is UB. If you try to cast the pointer returned by new, the compiler will tell you that you are trying to do something illegal.

Answer (score 2):

This has undefined behavior because the object is `const` and it is altered by `append`.  It *also* may have an issue with obtaining a pointer to the `string` via the `malloc` value rather than using the result of the `new`: an array is not pointer-interconvertible with its own first element, let alone an object for which it provides storage (which is itself only a C++17 term; this is an area of active *research*, for want of a better term).